# User is not permitted to create v$ or x$ in one of my oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

In my Oracle 19c, the oracle user I have created is not allowed to create v$ or x$ views. Is it restricted from the 12c version?

Comment: What does "not allowed" mean?

Comment: [Yes, according to Oracle support doc 2052646.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2052646.1). Doesn't seem to in the change notes though.

Answer (score 0):

It is allowed(But with **lowercase** `v$`), You just need to create it with name wrapped in the double quotes:

See issue:

```
SQL> create or replace view v$tejash
  2  as select * from dual;
create or replace view v$tejash
                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00999: invalid view name
```

same issue if I use the **upper case** `V$`

```
SQL> create or replace view "V$TEJASH"
  2  as select * from dual;
create or replace view "V$TEJASH"
                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00999: invalid view name


SQL>
```

Use **lowercase** `v$` and it is resolved.

```
SQL> create or replace view "v$tejash"
  2  as select * from dual;

View created.

SQL>
```

Although, It is not recommended to use such names.

Comment: Note that if you wrap a name in quotes to force case-sensitivity you will _always_ have to refer to the table name in quotes in all subsequent SQL. Also, just because you can do something doesn't mean you _should_. v$ and x$ names are typically reserved by Oracle for internal views and such and have very specific meanings in terms of what type of data they access. In order to avoid confusion and/or possible naming conflicts I would _never_ use those names in a custom application. Just pick another letter for your custom prefix.

Comment: Yes, very much true. @pmdba